Convergence of a power series taking values on distributions
Let us consider the following distribution-valued power series in the variable $z\in U\subset \mathbb{R}$ acting on test function $\phi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$:
$$\chi(z,w) \equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n \delta^{(n)}(w).\tag{1}$$
Here $\delta^{(n)}(w)$ is the $n$-th derivative of the one-dimensional Dirac delta distribution. This equality should as always be understood in the distributional sense, so given a test function $\phi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ we would have $$\langle \chi,\phi\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n \langle \delta^{(n)},\phi\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^na_n z^n \phi^{(n)}(0)\tag{2}.$$
My question here is: how does one make sense of the radius of convergence of a distribution-valued power series?
Usually one would consider for example the ratio test, but at the level of (1) the ratio test doesn't make sense. It would make sense for (2), but then it seems to give a result that highly depends on the test function under consideration. For example, the standard ratio test would demand us to study:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}a_{n+1}z^{n+1}\phi^{(n+1)}(0)}{(-1)^n a_n z^n \phi^{(n)}(0)}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}\phi^{(n+1)}(0)}{a_n\phi^{(n)}(0)}\right|\frac{1}{|z|}\tag{3}$$
and this seems to me as something that would definitely depend on $\phi$ in a non-trivial way.
So if we want to consider a power series taking values in distributions such as (1), what is the correct way to study its convergence properties and establish its radius of convergence?

The short answer is that it does not make much sense. (1) does not define a distribution, you first need to study the convergence of the series. In general, the radius of convergence makes sense in a Banach space, i.e. a complete normed space. However, the space of distribution with its usual topology is not even metrisable. At best you can look at the radius of convergence at a fixed test function. In other words, you can only study the weak convergence of the series. You could then define the radius of convergence of the distribution series as the lower bound of the radii of convergence of all the test functions. However, you expect generically that it is zero.
For example, take the fast decaying sequence:
$$
a_n=\frac1{n!}
$$
Intuitively, you would expect:
$$
\langle \chi,\phi\rangle=\phi(-z)
$$
which is a legitimate distribution. However, the series does not converge to the shift. For all $z\neq0$, the series does not converge weakly. You just need to consider a test function that is not analytic at $0$. In general due to possible rapid growth of the derivatives of a smooth function it is hard to even guarantee weak convergence of your series.

Another way of seeing that your series cannot define a distribution is the following. All distributions have "locally finite order". See pt.3 of Theorem 1 in this PlanetMath page. If that sum converged, it would have infinite order on any compact set of the form $[-a, a]$.
